# Can we have variables in a Yosys script?

Tags: yosys

I'd like to make my Yosys scripts more DRY by factoring out common parameters, such as in the following example:

```
read_liberty -lib  /long/path/to/lib/file
...
dfflibmap -liberty  /long/path/to/lib/file
...
abc  -liberty   /long/path/to/lib/file
```

I haven't found a way to declare or de-reference variables, is there any way like in TCL (`set lib_file /long/path/to/lib/file`) or Bash (`export lib_file=/long/path/to/lib/file`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use TCL. See `yosys -h tcl` for details. Run TCL scripts with `yosys -c <script_file>` (instead of `yosys -s <script_file>` for native Yosys scripts.)

I've now added front-end detection for .tcl files in commit b8d7f57. So starting with b8d7f57 you can also use `yosys <script_file>` to run a TCL script, if `<script_file>` ends with `.tcl`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this simplifies a few things. For the benefit of others: apart from running Yosys with the `-c` option, you'll also need to add the line `yosys -import` at the top of the script to make all Yosys commands available to the TCL interpreter and rename `proc` calls to `procs` as `proc` is a TCL reserved word.