# Parameters to Script

Tags: yosys

Is there some way to pass parameters (or command line arguments) to a Yosys script?

I see in this quetion ([Can we have variables in a Yosys script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062516/can-we-have-variables-in-a-yosys-script)) you can run the Yosys script within a TCL interpreter.  Is there some way to pass in an argument?

The reason I am doing this is that I have a script, and I want to be able to call the script with a parameterized path to a Verilog file.  Surely this is a common need, and there must be some easy way to do this, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to do that at the moment is using environment variables and TCL scripts. For example, you can write a TCL script `test.tcl`:

```
yosys read_verilog $::env(VLOG_FILE_NAME)
yosys synth -top $::env(TOP_MODULE)
yosys write_verilog output.v
```

And then call if with `VLOG_FILE_NAME` and `TOP_MODULE` set in the environment:

```
VLOG_FILE_NAME=tests/simple/fiedler-cooley.v TOP_MODULE=up3down5 yosys test.tcl
```

If you are running Yosys from a shell script you can also simply run something like `export VLOG_FILE_NAME=...` at the top of your script. Similarly you can use the `export` Makefile statement when you are running Yosys from a Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar case. This question showed up while I was working on a solution. I ended up with a different approach though:

I'm creating a wrapper to my top module, written in m4 language. It's very simple, it overrides the parameters value, and then includes my top module definition.

Then in the Makefile, I process the wrapper.m4 file, to create the resulting wrapper.v file, that will be input to yosys.

I have detailled the solution [here](https://maker.itnerd.space/define-verilog-parameters-at-synthesis-time-yosys/).